# No module named 'model'

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I am trying to use the CoAtNet class in the following link
[CoAtNet Class from Github](https://github.com/xmu-xiaoma666/External-Attention-pytorch/blob/master/model/attention/CoAtNet.py)
but I always have error while I am running the following lines:

```
from torch import nn, sqrt
import torch
import sys
from math import sqrt
#sys.path.append('.')
from model.conv.MBConv import MBConvBlock
from model.attention.SelfAttention import ScaledDotProductAttention
```

and I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

from this line:

```
from model.conv.MBConv import MBConvBlock
```

can any one helps me Regards in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just using the `CoAtNet.py` file it gives this error since it is missing relative imports from other folder in the repository (i.e. the `MBConvBlock` and `ScaledDotProductAttention` classes). Make sure to either clone the full repository or copy just the two python files ([`SelfAttention.py`](https://github.com/xmu-xiaoma666/External-Attention-pytorch/blob/c65bc649c900284d8f337ae08fea34c98b334e94/model/attention/SelfAttention.py#L8) and [`MBConv.py`](https://github.com/xmu-xiaoma666/External-Attention-pytorch/blob/c65bc649c900284d8f337ae08fea34c98b334e94/model/conv/MBConv.py#L94)) in which the two classes are defined.

Comment: thank you Oxbowerce!, it has been worked.